# Bootstrap: center li items in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get link1, link2 centered horizontally and vertically. I got the horizontal part working, but no matter what I've tried for vertical nothing changes.

Html code:

```
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %> -->
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li> -->
          <li>Link 1</li>
          <li>Link 2</li>
        </ul>
     </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Css code:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav
  display: inline-block
  float: none
  vertical-align: middle

.navbar .navbar-collapse
  text-align: center

/* link */
.navbar-nav > li
  margin: 3px
  text-transform: uppercase
  font-weight: bold
  color: white
```

How do I get this to work? And do you think that I should be using bootstrap or develop everything with css?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your css:

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: initial;
  line-height: 150px;
}
.nav>li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

`line-height` is the height of the `li` which makes them in the center of the block. Hope it was the thing you wanted.

Here is bootply: http://www.bootply.com/1Tiu9JzEBN#

Comment: I want the same effect as what you created, but without setting a line height. That just makes the navbar incredibly big.

Comment: ? I'm not sure what do you want to achieve, you don't have to add the line-height if you don't need it, but what exactly you want to align vertically than? Add the bootply for your case and detailed description you want, please.

Comment: I want the li items to be centered inside the nav. Anyway, I'm going to change to css. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align :center;
}

.navbar-nav > li span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li> -->
          <li><span>Link 1</span></li>
          <li><span>Link 2</span></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```